# Lenovo thinkpad E460 keyboard issue after skype call

Tags: lenovo, skype, thinkpad

I have Lenovo thinkpad E460 model laptop with Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I do a skype call just after disconnect skype call my keyboard behaves strange. To fix this I have to attach external keyboard and kill skype from terminal. My skype version is -8.56.0.102 Does anyone knows any fix for this.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue here with Thinkpad L580, ubuntu 19.10, skype 8.56.0.103. Exiting skype from the toolbar menu (with the mouse) temporarily solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yes same with me. In my case I have to lock the screen once and then open terminal somehow and kill the skype. If you find any solution let me know

Comment: Yes, facing same issue after 1:1 call. Everything works fine if I am on a group call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed in the recent versions of `skypeforlinux`. Upgrade Skype to `8.61.0.95` or a newer version.